# How to index 2d Numpy array with 2d integer array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I am looking to index a 2d array with a 2d array of integers. The goal is to index each column separately, however, i can't seem to find the right syntax for this.

I understand why the naive x[s] does not work, but can only get it to work in an inefficient list comprehension.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(size=(10, 5))
s = np.argsort(x, 0)
```

What i hoped would work, but shape is (10, 5, 5)

```
x[s]
```

Desired outcome,  shape: (10, 5)

```
np.vstack([x[s[:, i], i] for i in range(len(x[0]))]).T # -> shape is (10, 5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `s` to index into rows of `x` if you also specify the columns:

```
# The list comprehension that you know works correctly
correct_result = np.vstack([x[s[:, i], i] for i in range(len(x[0]))]).T

# Indexing by also specifying column indices
result = x[s, range(x.shape[1])]

print((result == correct_result).all()) # True
```

Comment: It's slightly faster to use `np.arange`, i.e. `x[s, np.arange(x.shape[1])]`.